# Seeing other users' folders on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

Hi two questions on sharing for Windows 7.

**Question 1**
I was shocked to find out I was able to see a bunch of folders accessible over the network, and I was able to access everyone's directories from another PC over the network.  I have since then disabled via the following steps.  Is this the correct way for doing this?

1. Click on Start
2. Right click on Computer -> click on Manage
3. Expand System Tools -> Shared Folders, click on Shares
4. Right click on everything (except ADMIN$, C$, IPC$) -> click Stop Sharing

**Question 2**
I'm still able to see other users' folders from within the PC when I'm logged in.  I'm the admin but still I don't think I should be able to see everyone's contents.  How do I stop this?

Thanks.

Comment: You setup the permissions so you could view their files. If you want to disable your access to other user's files then remove your ability to do so. Make sure thats what mangement wants though.  I suppose its not a huge deal to simply change the ownership properties of the folder within share if you change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the admin on both computers and have the same username and password, you will automatically log yourself in to the other computer when you try to access it.

So, if you are an admin and have permissions to see other's files on the machine locally, you will see them over the network.

However, I think you are seeing them purely because the files are accessible and not because of any admin escalation... for question one, to stop this is the same as question 2, the individual users need to make their files private.

... This changes depending on the version of Windows as you may not have the security tab visible... You need to basically go to c:\users and find the person, then remove the ability for administrator and/or guests to view the files.

Comment: Thanks.  It's Windows 7 I'm using.  Can you elaborate on "... This changes depending on the version of Windows as you may not have the security tab visible... You need to basically go to c:\users and find the person, then remove the ability for administrator and/or guests to view the files."?

Comment: If you are not using 7 Pro, enterprise or ultimate, you may not have the security tab as an option. You will need to go to the command prompt and use the takeown command instead.

Comment: Okay I'm on Win 7 Pro and I found the Security tab.  If I right click on C drive -> Properties -> Security tab, I see the following:  1) Admin:  Full Control; 2) SYSTEM:  Full control; 3) Users:  Read & execute; 4) Authenticated Users:  Special; 5) Authenticated Users:  Create folders / append data.  Which are the default ones?